# Misunderstood quote from Learn JavaFX 17

Tags: java, javafx

I am going through the book "Learn JavaFX 17" and it has been very helpful so far.  However, I came across something on page 92 which seems to fly in the face of the examples.  Just after the tip the authors say:

> It is allowed, but not advisable, to change the content of a ListProperty whose content has been bound to another ObservableList. In such cases, the bound ListProperty will not be synchronized with its target list.

Yet the very next example seems to show a ListProperty, bound to another whose content changes, and the bound ListProperty changes as well.

I think I have missed the point of this quote entirely.  I expect there is some subtle distinction being made that I am not seeing.

Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: How _did_ you understand the quote?

Comment: I'm not sure, now, that I did.  This is what confuses me.  It sounds like the authors are saying you can't modify a bound property but the examples show doing exactly that.  So I really don't know what they mean by that quoted text.

Comment: But, after some thought I suppose it may have something to do with directionality.  I'm just not sure how to parse the comment.

Comment: I'm guessing blindly here (because I don't have the book, and you didn't provide enough context to understand the question in isolation), but what they likely mean is that if `listProperty` is a `ListProperty` that is bound (i.e. you've called `listProperty.bind(someOtherListProperty)`, then `listProperty.set(...)` is not allowed (will throw an exception), but modifying the list wrapped by the list property, e.g. `listProperty.get().add(...)` is allowed but will cause the bindings to be out of sync.

Comment: But really, you should provide enough information in the question that it can be properly understood without any external reference.

Comment: Thanks, @James_D.  I think that is probably what they meant.  Since I wasn't sure what the comment meant I wasn't quite sure what to provide.  The listing was long enough to make me think twice before adding it to the question.  IOW, the ambiguity of the statement as it stands is the problem I was trying to solve.  I think you solved it.

Comment: If that is what they mean, I'm not actually sure they're correct.

Comment: @slaw Ah, I was interpreting "bound" differently. The only way I can see `list1` and `list2` diverging is via changing the state of an element of one list, in which case the other list will not receive notifications (except by using observable properties and extractors). But again, I don't have the book, so I'm just having to extrapolate here anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the book, but that quote mentions bound "content", and so the only reasonable thing it could be talking about is the [`#bindContent(ObservableList)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.base/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyListProperty.html#bindContent(javafx.collections.ObservableList))<sup>**1**</sup> method. If you call that method, then changes to the `ObservableList` will be reflected in the `ListProperty`<sup>**2**</sup> but not vice versa.

For example:

```java
import javafx.beans.property.ListProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleListProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObservableList<String> foo = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ObservableList<String> bar = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        ListProperty<String> property = new SimpleListProperty<>(foo);
        property.bindContent(bar);

        bar.add("Hello");
        // same as 'property.get().add("World")' (i.e., adds directly to 'foo')
        property.add("World");

        System.out.println("FOO: " + foo);
        System.out.println("BAR: " + bar);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
FOO: [Hello, World]
BAR: [Hello]
```

You can use the [`#bindContentBidirectional(ObservableList)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.base/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyListProperty.html#bindContentBidirectional(javafx.collections.ObservableList))<sup>**1**</sup> method instead if you want changes to be reflected in both directions.

For example:

```java
import javafx.beans.property.ListProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleListProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObservableList<String> foo = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ObservableList<String> bar = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        ListProperty<String> property = new SimpleListProperty<>(foo);
        // only change from previous example
        property.bindContentBidirectional(bar);

        bar.add("Hello");
        // same as 'property.get().add("World")' (i.e., adds directly to 'foo')
        property.add("World");

        System.out.println("FOO: " + foo);
        System.out.println("BAR: " + bar);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
FOO: [Hello, World]
BAR: [Hello, World]
```

---

<sup>**1.** These methods are declared in the [`ReadOnlyListProperty`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.base/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyListProperty.html) class. Note the "read-only" bit only refers the ability to change the value of the *property*; the list remains modifiable (unless you initialize/set the value to an unmodifiable list).</sup>

<sup>**2.** More specifically, the underlying `ObservableList` value of the `ListProperty` is synchronized with the given `ObservableList`. Though this happens "via the `ListProperty`".</sup>

Comment: Your very first line is a reason to vote to close the question, not answer it. Do not answer questions that do not supply code. [answer]

Comment: @Rob Although I (had) put that disclaimer, I'm still 95%+ sure I'm correct. And given that, I felt the question provided _just enough_ context to be answerable. Otherwise, I would have voted to close. If I'm wrong, the OP will tell me, and then I'll delete this answer. I also disagree that every question needs to have code on this site.

Comment: Thanks, @Slaw.  Between this answer and the comment by James_D, I think this probably covers what the authors intended.  I wish I could have given more information in the question but my question was regarding an ambiguous statement in the first place so I was looking for any insight into how to understand the statement.